# D3 select nodes and display array information

Tags: arrays, d3.js

Good morning everyone.
I am using the force layout D3 template and i want to display in the circle.append("title") the values of select nodes and their respective generations.

Throught the array of strings (Array = ["0","100","200","300","2","100","200","300","8","100","200","300","400","500","600"])

-"0", "2", and "8" are the node numbers and the rest is the generation numbers.

circle.append("title")
    .text(function(d){

```
for(x in nodeNumbWduplicates){
  for(w=0; w<fullNodeArray; w++){

  }

  if ((d.name === nodeNumbWduplicates[x]  )) {
       return ("StID:" + " " + StID + " " + "Generation:" + " " + Node);

    }

}
});
```

I need to return a kind of split of the array with the respective generations for esach node.

Example:

Display : Node: 0 Generations: 100, 200, 300. ("0","100","200","300").

Any suggestion please.

Regards

Comment: Note: I need to split the array for a range od selected nodes

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Is all you're asking how to split a string?

Comment: The main point is slip the array os strings, although this array chang when the selection change, so first of all i needto know how to slip the array by node and generation as i mention before

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. What are these generations? I assume you mean "split" and not "slip"?

Comment: I only want split the array in slices.
This slices
"0","100","200","300"
"2","100","200","300"
"8","100","200","300", "400","500","600"

and then print on the display that node = 0 have the generations 100, 200 and 300

and so on.

Comment: If I understand correctly then it would be much easier to reorganise your data before passing it to D3.